# Insufficient number of observations in cross-sectional dependence tests in Stata

Tags: stata, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am analyzing the impact of 3rd and 4th division soccer teams (1), their stadiums (2), and their affiliation to 1st & 2nd division teams VS. independence (3) on per capita GDP on county-level using a panel data set with `N = 266` counties and `T = 18` (1995-2012). In total, there are 29 independent variables, many of them dummies.

I tried to compute the Pesaran CD test using the command `xtcsd, pes` in `Stata 12` to check whether my panel data set suffers from cross-sectional dependence. It is a post-estimation command for use with cross-section time-series data following *fixed effetcs* or *random effects* models. It is especially useful in panel data models with small T and large N. For further information, check: [General diagnostic tests for cross section dependence in panels, Pesaran (2004)](http://www.econ.cam.ac.uk/research/repec/cam/pdf/cwpe0435.pdf). Although it seems to fit my data set (small T and large N), I always get an error message.

These are the commands I used and the results I get:

```
. xtset countyid year, yearly
   panel variable:  countyid (strongly balanced)
    time variable:  year, 1995 to 2012
            delta:  1 year

. xtreg realpci12 realpci12lagged percentchangepop unemploymentrate 
  stadiumcap nrfirstbundteams nrsecondbundteams qualityaffiliation 
  nrfirstdivicehockeyteams nrfirstdivbasketteams nrfirstdivhballteams 
  nrthirddivteams nrfourthdivteams stadyear stadrenov thirddivstadhoney 
  fourthdivstadhoney nrpromofifthtofourth nrpromofourthtothird 
  nrpromothirdtosecond nrrelesecondtothird nrrelethirdtofourth 
  nrrelefourthtofifth nrrelefourthtosixth, fe

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs = 3761
Group variable: countyid                        Number of groups = 266

R-sq:  within  = 0.5536                         Obs per group: min =         2
       between = 0.9979                                        avg =      14.1
       overall = 0.9833                                        max =        17

                                                F(23,3472)         =    187.24
corr(u_i, Xb)  = 0.9718                         Prob > F           =    0.0000

           realpci12 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95%     Conf. Interval]

     realpci12lagged |   .7237805   .0129458    55.91   0.000     .6983984    .7491627
    percentchangepop |  -336.6341   61.06093    -5.51   0.000     -456.353   -216.9151
    unemploymentrate |  -114.9001   14.39359    -7.98   0.000    -143.1208   -86.67932
          stadiumcap |   .0006133   .0062043     0.10   0.921    -.0115512    .0127778
    nrfirstbundteams |   312.7065   230.9308     1.35   0.176    -140.0675    765.4804
   nrsecondbundteams |   222.7542   181.1701     1.23   0.219    -132.4565    577.9649
  qualityaffiliation |   -.000141    .000756    -0.19   0.852    -.0016234    .0013413
 nr1stdivhockeyteams |   695.1087   215.3585     3.23   0.001     272.8666    1117.351
 nr1stdivbasketteams |   159.0625   185.6213     0.86   0.392    -204.8754    523.0005
   nrstdivhballteams |   141.3413   187.0341     0.76   0.450    -225.3667    508.0492
     nrthirddivteams |   117.0015   110.7597     1.06   0.291    -100.1593    334.1623
    nrfourthdivteams |   -19.8552   82.16867    -0.24   0.809     -180.959    141.2486
            stadyear |  -.0155347   .0502977    -0.31   0.757    -.1141508    .0830814
           stadrenov |   -203.364   164.7056    -1.23   0.217    -526.2936    119.5656
   thirddivstadhoney |  -19.29619   312.8604    -0.06   0.951    -632.7051    594.1127
  fourthdivstadhoney |   15.80935   252.1322     0.06   0.950     -478.533    510.1518
nrpromofifthtofourth |   34.08999   88.77364     0.38   0.701    -139.9638    208.1438
nrpromofourthtothird |   93.34921   159.0309     0.59   0.557    -218.4543    405.1527
nrpromothirdtosecond |   88.02121   216.7625     0.41   0.685    -336.9737    513.0162
 nrrelesecondtothird |   75.15901   250.9754     0.30   0.765    -416.9154    567.2334
 nrrelethirdtofourth |  -131.4062   147.8868    -0.89   0.374    -421.3601    158.5477
 nrrelefourthtofifth |   15.25888   90.42343     0.17   0.866    -162.0296    192.5474
 nrrelefourthtosixth |   151.6347   429.5927     0.35   0.724    -690.6452    993.9145
               _cons |   9704.952   467.3823    20.76   0.000      8788.58    10621.32

             sigma_u |   3347.205
             sigma_e |  1473.7412
                 rho |  .83762241   (fraction of variance due to u_i)

F test that all u_i=0:     F(265, 3472) =     2.34           Prob > F = 0.0000

. xtcsd, pes
Error: The panel is highly unbalanced.
Not enough common observations across panel to perform Pesaran's test.
insufficient observations
r(2001);

. xtcsd, fri
no observations
r(2000);

. xtcsd, frees
no observations
r(2000);
```

I reproduced the problem with a smaller data set and got the following Stata output:

```
. xtset id year
   panel variable:  id (strongly balanced)
    time variable:  year, 1998 to 2010
            delta:  1 unit

. xtreg income populationchange unemploymentrate, fe

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs      =      1755
Group variable: id                              Number of groups   =       147

R-sq:  within  = 0.0565                         Obs per group: min =         2
       between = 0.0079                                        avg =      11.9
       overall = 0.0036                                        max =        13

                                            F(2,1606)          =     48.10
corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.0107                    Prob > F           =    0.0000


          income |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]

populationchange |   -456.708   113.8797    -4.01   0.000    -680.0764   -233.3396
unemploymentrate |  -224.9462   26.35677    -8.53   0.000    -276.6435    -173.249
           _cons |   33402.62   277.3417   120.44   0.000     32858.63    33946.61

         sigma_u |  12015.507
         sigma_e |  1758.9465
             rho |  .97901966   (fraction of variance due to u_i)

F test that all u_i=0:     F(146, 1606) =   563.21           Prob > F =     0.0000

. xtcsd, pes
unknown function *sqrt()
r(133);

. xtcsd, fri
insufficient observations
r(2001);

. xtcsd, frees
insufficient observations
r(2001);
```

I guess the problem is that some of the variables have missing values. If I run the test statistics with variables that have no missing values, they are computed without a problem. Nevertheless, I would like to run these tests with the full model (not just the variables with no missing values). Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Any help is highly appreciated.

If further explanation and/or information is needed, please let me know.

Kind regards,

Alex

Comment: It isn't clear to me if this is ultimately a Stata coding issue (in which case it would be off topic here), or a statistical issue (on topic). Either way, it will be difficult to diagnose without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); can you add one?

Comment: @gung What information exactly are you missing?

Comment: Mostly I don't know enough about the tests you are running & I don't know Stata. Others here will know 1 or the other, or both. But they will need a reproducible example to work with.

Comment: @gung I tried to make it more reproducible. If something is missing, please let me know.

Comment: This is nice, but the econometricians here are going to know those methods already. What they will need is a reproducible example so they can try what you're doing & discover whether you are using the commands incorrectly, or if you're misunderstanding the methods. (You can learn what a reproducible example is at the link.) Without a reproducible example, how will they be able to figure out the cause of this error message?

Comment: @gung I added all the commands I use and all the relevant Stata outputs. Since I cannot upload the data set itself, this all the information I can provide.

Comment: Can you add code creating a fake datatset that reproduces these errors? If the errors cannot be reproduced, I don't see how anyone is going to be able to tell you how to fix them.